# How do I turn off the Issues banner in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Recently Chrome Dev Tools has added an annoying banner that covers the top of the console. Besides hitting the "X" every time, how can I disable the banner for good?

[image: The Issues banner]

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you know specifically which flag needs to be disabled?

Comment: Oops, there's no way anymore.

Comment: Is there no way to get rid of it yet? It is super annoying during development

Answer (score -3):

It was heppening to me when developing my website. Quite annoying. Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311280/7663959